# Clarity Data Grid + Card Functionality

Tags: angular, angular8, vmware-clarity

A newbie to Clarity in general, but after extensive googling I have found no example, even a simple one to implement a grid view in card layout.

Example:
[Adobe prototype](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jlSU.png)

Clarity's [documentation](https://v2.clarity.design/cards) says that it is entirely possible to switch between card and list view, was wondering how though.

Comment: The switching recommendation is related to two views of one data model. Lets say you have an object that lists books. each book will have details and an image perhaps. The recommendation is that the app could implement both a card view of the book (with the image and only important high level data) _and_ a datagrid view with columns for all of the data. This is just a rough example for how to think about that. This is easily implemented in Angular with an `*ngIf` in the template that the user can toggle the view with.

Comment: Well the switching isn't the problem. The problem is the card view with inline editing function.

Comment: Can you make a stackblitz that shows the code your are working with? We keep starters here: https://stackblitz.com/@clr-team

Answer (score 0):

Clarity doesn't have inbuilt way to switch between card and list view. You need to implement your own component to do that OR use `*ngIf` to switch between 2 templates which shows same data in different form.